# How to concat rows separated by a space in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, whitespace, concatenation, listagg

I am trying to concat/merge rows in a table to one single row. I tried using listagg but due to varchar limitation this doesn't work.

```
create table tmp(word VARCHAR2(4000),
                 lvl NUMBER);

insert into tmp2 values('python',1);
insert into tmp2 values('java',2);

select listagg(word,' ') within group(order by lvl) as listagg_output from tmp;
```

The output should look like python java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will you do with such a long string?

Anyway, have a look at this example; if `listagg` won't work, `xmlagg` will.

```
SQL> create table test (id, col) as
  2  select rownum, a.column_name
  3  from user_tab_columns a cross join user_tab_columns b
  4  cross join user_tab_columns c;

Table created.

SQL> select count(*) from test;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      9261

SQL> select listagg(col, ' ') within group (order by null) result from test;
select listagg(col, ' ') within group (order by null) result from test
                                                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long


SQL> select length(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, col, ' ').extract('//text()') order by null).GetClobVal()) length_result
  2  from test;

LENGTH_RESULT
-------------
        51156

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pretty simple:

1. You created the table `tmp`
2. You inserted your test data into the table `tmp2`
3. Your query against `tmp` returned no results because there was no data in `tmp`

The solution is to insert your test data into `tmp`:

```
create table tmp(word VARCHAR2(4000),
                 lvl NUMBER);

insert into tmp values('python',1);
insert into tmp values('java',2);

select listagg(word,' ') within group(order by lvl) as listagg_output from tmp;
```

This now returns `python java`

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=788c9f3a242aa6264050983e5f486310)