# Select multiple data from one column and update the combine result to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I have a table 'table A' as below and I want to select these data into one column and the result will update table B

```
+-----------+
| ID | Name |
+-----------+
| 1  |a     |
+-----------+
| 2  |b     |
+-----------+
| 3  |c     |
+-----------+
```

Result:

```
Name
-----
a b c
```

Comment: Please mention the DBMS that are you using. Oracle? MySQL etc.,?

Comment: I'm using sql server

Comment: this topic has been covered hundreds of times here. How to do it in [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle), [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629622/how-to-concat-rows-separated-by-a-space-in-oracle), [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Comment: SQL server 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `STRING_AGG()`

```
SELECT
    STRING_AGG(name,' ') Name
FROM
    yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `stuff()` function.

```
select
   stuff((select (' ' + cast([name] as varchar(30)) )
                      from test2 t2
                        for xml path('')
                    ), 1, 1, '' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
Declare @Names varchar(max)
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + Name 
FROM TableA

INSERT INTO TableB(Name)
SELECT REPLACE(@Names,',',' ')
```